# Integrate google analytics api in ASP.NET mvc5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-api, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I want to show goolge analytics report in my application.
I want my user to be able to see his website's google analytics report in my application without going to google analytics site.
can you anyone tell me how to do this, or if this is possible to do in ASP.NET MVC5 Project?
Thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This answer has nothing to do with ASP.NET, but you can display Google Analytics data in any web page via the Google Analytics APIs.

In particular, the Embed API make it very easy to display your Google Analytics data in Google Charts, and it handles most of the authentication piece for you.

Here's the documentation for the Embed API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed

And here a demo site with examples:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/demos/embed-api/